# Are the real and imaginary parts of the complex number $(-1/2)^{(-1/2)^{(-1/2)}}$ irrational? Transcendental?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

> ***Question:*** Are the real and imaginary parts of the complex number $(-1/2)^{(-1/2)^{(-1/2)}}$ irrational? Transcendental ?

Background and motivation: I became curious about numbers writable as $$\Bigg |(-1/n)^{(-1/n)^{(-1/n)}} \Bigg|$$ This was motivated by me trying to [write](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2566614/quickly-show-that-bigg-1-2-1-2-1-2-bigg-e-pi-sqrt2) $e^{\pi\sqrt{2}}.$ Now [Gelfond-Schneider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem) tells us that $e^{\pi\sqrt{2}}$ is irrational and transcendental. On the other hand I know that $(-1/n)^{(-1/n)^{(-1/n)}}$ is a complex number in particular there exist real numbers $z_0$ and $z_1$ such that $$(-1/n)^{(-1/n)^{(-1/n)}}=z_0+iz_1 $$ For example if $n$ is equal to $2$: $$(-1/2)^{(-1/2)^{(-1/2)}}= \color{blue}{47.339658423\ldots}+i\color{blue}{70.6208560994\ldots}$$ I do not believe Gelfond-Schneider shows $47.339658423\ldots$ and $70.6208560994\ldots$ to be irrational or transcendental.

Comment: You must first choose a branch for the square root...

Comment: Could you elaborate ?

Comment: @AnthonyHernandez Do you know what is [principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value)?

Comment: @AlexVong vaguely. I believe the principal value relates to $arg(z)$ for some complex number $z$.

Comment: @AnthonyHernandez The problem is that $\arg z$ is multi-valued and $\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ is by definition $e^{-\frac{1}{2} \log -\frac{1}{2}}$ where $\log z = \log |z| + i \arg z$, so you need to choose a branch for $\arg z$ so that $\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ becomes singled-valued.

Comment: @alexvong preumably I should be using the principle branch.